# Joining two df with condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two df.
`df1` has over 2 milion rows and has complete data. I'd like to join data from `df2`, which has over 70.000 rows but it's structure is a bit complicated.
df1 has for eac row keys `KO-STA` and `KO-PAR`.
df2 has in some cases data only on `KO-STA`, in some cases only on `KO-PAR` and in some case on both.
I'd like to merge those two df and get the data on `Need1` and `Need2`.

df1

```
          STA_SID   DST_SID        CC   KO_SIFKO    KO-STA       KO-PAR
135  10021582  28878502            NaN       634    634-83        537-780/9   
117  10028732  29999540            NaN       657  657-1729        537-780/4
117  10028732  29999541            NaN       657  657-1729        537-780/4
117  10028732  29999542            NaN       657  657-1729        537-780/4
117  10028732  29999543            NaN       657  657-1729        537-780/4
117  10028732  31356572            NaN       657  657-1729        537-780/4

df2

        KO-STA  STA-PAR       KO-PAR          Need1       Need2  \
0   1976-_    366/2   1976-366/2                Bio       49.500000   
1    991-_  329/128  991-329/128                 PH      184.399994   
2  2147---    96/19   2147-96/19                Win        8.850000   
3   2048-_    625/4   2048-625/4                SSE        4.940000   
4   2194-_    285/3   2194-285/3               TI f      163.000000   
5  2386---     97/1    2386-97/1                Bio       49.500000   
6   2002-_   2002/9  2002-2002/9                Win       12.850000   
7   1324-_       62      1324-62                Win        8.850000   
8   1625-_    980/1   1625-980/1                Win        8.850000   
9   1625-_    980/1   1625-980/1                Bio       49.500000
```

My attempt was with the following code

```
GURS_ES1 = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on = 'KO-STA')
GURS_ES2 = pd.merge(GURS_ES1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on = 'KO-PAR')
```

But after the first merge, GURS_ES1 has two indexes `KO-PAR_x` and `KO-PAR_y` and it doesn't join them as one column. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide you an example to make sure how you can proceed an what is the reason for the behaviour you observed:

First, let's construct our sample data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,3,size=(3,3)),columns=['a1','x1','x2'])
```

Output

```
   a1   x1  x2
0   1   2   1
1   2   1   1
2   1   2   2
```

Now, the other dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,3,size=(3,3)),columns=['a2','x1','x2'])

    a2  x1  x2
0   2   2   1
1   1   2   2
2   1   1   2
```

Now, if we merge on only(!) one of the indices which occur in both dataframes, then pandas wants you to be able to reconstruct from which dataframe the index originally came

```
pd.merge(df1,df2, on='x1')
```

Output

```
   a1  x1 x2_x a2 x2_y
0   1   2   1   2   1
1   1   2   1   1   2
2   1   2   2   2   1
3   1   2   2   1   2
4   2   1   1   1   2
```

Now, the easiest way to get rid of this is to drop one of the double occuring columns in one of the dataframes:

```
pd.merge(df1[df1.columns.drop('x2')], df2, on='x1')
```

Output

```
    a1  x1  a2  x2
0   1   2   2   1
1   1   2   1   2
2   1   2   2   1
3   1   2   1   2
4   2   1   1   2
```

But you could also merge on a list of columns. Note that we perform an inner join here, which can reduce the number of rows in the output dataframa significantly (or even lead to empty dataframes if there are no matches on both columns)

```
pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['x1','x2'])

    a1  x1  x2  a2
0   1   2   1   2
1   1   2   2   1
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand everything, tried the proposed but i get an Empty DataFrame. I work with 5 % of the entire databases, so i don't have to wait for the process time. Nevertheless, if there are no matches - than values should be `NaN`.